# How do I make text come out out of an impossible space?

Tags: animation

I'm looking to recreate the text being generated by two horizontal bars in the Marvel logo https://youtu.be/fqxIrmdtLEk?t=25s (@00.25 secs)
I've already generated the text, just looking for a way to achieve the animation part of it.

Comment: What do you mean by impossible space?

Comment: I mean the horizontal bars generating the text, like in the above video.

Comment: Ok. UNderstood. Just give a look to my answer. Is it clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need a text and two couple of cubes.

First couple of cubes: you can simply create a single cube, mirror it (with a modifier, on z axis. Don't apply the modifier) and move it up (Z axis) in edit mode to see it's twin. In edit mode hook the whole geometry to an empty object.

Second couple of cubes: duplicate the first (they will be hooked to the same hook) and in edit mode scale them bigger to cover all the writing.

Convert the text into a mesh (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and add a boolean modifier to it (difference with the second couple of cubes).

Now if you move the hook you'll get this:

[image]